# get a reference to timestamp in an embedded kibana chart in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kibana-4

In the picture in the following link the black box labeled @timestamp lists a date and time (sorry you need a 10 reputation to post an image)

https://www.elastic.co/assets/bltde09cbafb09b7f08/Screen-Shot-2014-09-30-at-4.07.15-PM.png

I have a kibana 4 dashboard embedded in a webpage and I would like to get access to these timestamps. An ideal behavior would be when a node is clicked the time stamp is printed in the console.

I have already suppressed the same-origin policy.

Has anyone performed something similar? I would appreciate any solution or insight.

Comment: but you have ten rep...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to grab it using jQuery's .contains selector:

```
$(':contains(@timestamp)').click(function(){
    var info = $(this).parent().find(':contains(,)').html();
    console.log(info);
});
```